# Ethernet desktop loses connection, but not wifi desktop

Tags: windows-10, router, ethernet

**What are the likely points of failure I should investigate?**

I have two desktop computers connected to the same Comcast-provided router. One is connected via ethernet and the other by USB wifi adapter. Over the past twelve hours I've had them logging their ability to ping comcast.net using the following command line:

```
ping -t comcast.net|cmd /q /v /c "(pause&pause)>nul & for /l %a in () do (set /p "data=" && echo(!date! !time! !data!)&ping -n 2 comcast.net>nul" >pinglog.txt
```

The wifi desktop has had 100% success.

The ethernet desktop has had 15 periods of lost connectivity. See below for an example from the logs.

Both desktops are running Windows 10.

Because of its location, it's going to be a pain to try ethernet on the wifi desktop. I'll give the wifi adapter a shot on the ethernet desktop when I can spare it.

**Ethernet Desktop:**

```
2016-07-25 23:25:03.62 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=57
2016-07-25 23:25:04.67 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=57
2016-07-25 23:25:05.99 General failure.
2016-07-25 23:25:06.47 General failure.
2016-07-25 23:25:11.19 Request timed out.
2016-07-25 23:25:16.18 Request timed out.
2016-07-25 23:25:27.27 Request timed out.
2016-07-25 23:25:32.18 Request timed out.
2016-07-25 23:25:37.17 Request timed out.
2016-07-25 23:25:39.18 Reply from 10.0.0.127: 
2016-07-25 23:25:39.20 Destination host unreachable.
2016-07-25 23:25:43.18 Request timed out.
2016-07-25 23:25:54.38 Request timed out.
2016-07-25 23:26:05.47 Request timed out.
2016-07-25 23:26:09.18 Request timed out.
2016-07-25 23:26:14.18 Request timed out.
2016-07-25 23:26:16.17 Reply from 10.0.0.127: 
2016-07-25 23:26:16.19 Destination host unreachable.
2016-07-25 23:26:20.18 Request timed out.
2016-07-25 23:26:25.18 Request timed out.
2016-07-25 23:26:26.29 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=57
2016-07-25 23:26:27.42 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=32ms TTL=57
2016-07-25 23:26:28.52 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=57
```

**Wifi Desktop:**

```
Mon 07/25/2016 23:25:03.61 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=57
Mon 07/25/2016 23:25:04.66 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=57
Mon 07/25/2016 23:25:05.70 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=57
Mon 07/25/2016 23:25:06.74 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=57
Mon 07/25/2016 23:25:07.78 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=57
Mon 07/25/2016 23:25:08.82 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=57
Mon 07/25/2016 23:25:09.87 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=57
Mon 07/25/2016 23:25:10.91 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=57
Mon 07/25/2016 23:25:11.95 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=57
Mon 07/25/2016 23:25:13.04 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=57
Mon 07/25/2016 23:25:14.08 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=57
Mon 07/25/2016 23:25:15.12 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=57
Mon 07/25/2016 23:25:16.17 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=57
Mon 07/25/2016 23:25:17.22 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=57
Mon 07/25/2016 23:25:18.27 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=57
Mon 07/25/2016 23:25:19.32 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=57
Mon 07/25/2016 23:25:20.36 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=57
Mon 07/25/2016 23:25:21.40 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=36ms TTL=57
Mon 07/25/2016 23:25:22.50 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=57
Mon 07/25/2016 23:25:23.54 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=32ms TTL=57
Mon 07/25/2016 23:25:24.60 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=57
Mon 07/25/2016 23:25:25.64 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=57
Mon 07/25/2016 23:25:26.68 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=57
Mon 07/25/2016 23:25:27.73 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=57
Mon 07/25/2016 23:25:28.77 Reply from 69.252.80.75: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=57
```

Comment: Start by looking at the router logs and configuration. The cause that springs to mind is a possible IP address clash: try assigning to the Ethernet interface a fixed address which is outside the DHCP range.

Comment: Do pings to other devices in the LAN also show this same packet loss?

Answer (score 3):

When pinging in Windows, `General Failure` usually indicates that the NIC hardware link is down altogether.  I would check the cabling between the computer and the router.  A pinched wire, broken clip, bent pins, or a loose connector could cause this.

1. Try using a different port on the router if one is available.
2. If it behaves the same, you're going to need to try a different Ethernet cable.
3. If the different cable behaves the same (or one is not available), try a different computer on the same cable to compare results.
4. If none of this works, the problem is likely with your NIC or your router.  Try another NIC (borrow a USB one) if you can.

Your Comcast router logs may have more information to add if you can access them.

Comment: The cable itself has seen better days. I'll try a new cable with the same desktop overnight as a troubleshooting tactic. The cable runs through the floor, so replacement is not my first choice.

Comment: Another thing to try is using a Linux live boot disk, such as Knoppix or the Ubuntu installation disk.  It will let you test the same hardware with a different OS.  If you have the same results, then you can be reasonably sure that it's not a software or driver problem on the computer.